# Is there a performance difference for these two Hive queries joining two tables with first letter partition key?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Suppose both table A and B have mid_key as their partition key.

Method 1

```
SELECT *
FROM A
    JOIN B ON A .mid_key = B.mid_key
    AND A .mid = B.mid
```

Method 2

```
SELECT *
FROM A
    JOIN B ON AND A .mid = B.mid
```

`mid_key` comes from `SUBSTR(mid, 1, 1) AS mid_key`, it has about fifty partitions
table A and B has about 600 million rows
Will the 1st query be faster?

Answer (score 0):

First sql will perform better because you have a partition key on mid_key.

If mid_key is the partition key then it will be used while joining two tables and HDFS scan will choose only those partitions that exist in both tables and ignore others. So, lot less I/O and faster performance because hive divides data on partition key into separate folder.